# Debian bullseye linux, Ros2 humble, binary package

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, debian, linux, binary

I am trying to install ROS2 humble on my Debian 11 bullseye.
(A proccess that I have done before very easy on Ubuntu)

From some reason, I don't find instructions on how to do it.
All the instructions are either deprecated or point to sudo add-apt-repository universe
(and universe is not known on debian !!!)

Can you please direct me to correct repo ?
Or to correct installation instructions ?

Thanks
Omatza